# PHP casting not working

Tags: php

Hi I am a newbie and  trying to fixing a tiny problem since 24hrs but still no luck.

```
<?php
$MOBILE=7372739; 
$PASSWORD="some_pass";

$PASSWORD=(string)$PASSWORD;
$MOBILE=(string)$MOBILE;  
//even tried $MOBILE="".$MOBILE; and $MOBILE="$MOBILE";


if(!(isset($PASSWORD)&& !empty($PASSWORD) && strlen($PASSWORD<=50))){
die("break1");
}

if(!(isset($MOBILE)&& !empty($MOBILE) && strlen($MOBILE<=50))){
die("break2");
}

?>
```

OUTPUT:
break2

If I am using string `$MOBILE="xyz";` not getting break2.

Why always getting break2? Please help. Thank you

Comment: Do you want to get `break2` or no? Your question is unclear.

Comment: I don't want break2. I am trying to check if user mobile number length not greater than 50 (upto 50 digit) so I can process signup further

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are checking to see if $MOBILE is smaller than 50, and it is, so the script dies, the < needs to be a > (in one scenario of what you may want), see below

```
<?php
$MOBILE=7372739; 
$PASSWORD="some_pass";

$PASSWORD=(string)$PASSWORD;
$MOBILE=(string)$MOBILE;  
//even tried $MOBILE="".$MOBILE; and $MOBILE="$MOBILE";


if(!(isset($PASSWORD)&& !empty($PASSWORD) && strlen($PASSWORD<=50))){
die("break1");
}

if(!(isset($MOBILE)&& !empty($MOBILE) && strlen($MOBILE>=50))){
die("break2");
}

?>
```

But that's not your problem is it?

You are additionally turning $MOBILE into a string right there in your code, and strlen checks the string length. If you want to check the **value** of it and not the length of the string, remove `$MOBILE=(string)$MOBILE;` and remove the strlen from the mobile check and **then** you can switch that $MOBILE sign back to <

Comment: I am checking $MOBILE is less than 50 if(!(strlen($MOBILE<=50)) I am inverting condition look ! . so it should not fall into if block

Comment: No. You are checking if the length of mobile as a __string__ is less than 50. The difference is this --- $MOBILE = (string)100 or $MOBILE = 100. You have to know the difference in integers and strings. Since you are checking strlen() which is the length of a string it will always return 3, so therefor it is smaller than 50, so there for it dies with your die('break2');

Comment: Is there way to coverting numeric value to string like $MOBILE=232 to $MOBILE="232" so I can check the length using strlen so it will return 3

Comment: You are already doing that. So what are you trying to accomplish here. Your original code will print break2 because it is logically set that way. As long as you want $MOBILE string to be smaller than 50 characters it will die('break2'). I am sorry I am unsure how to provide this more clear.

Comment: I think you are right sorry for your trouble I am not sleep since 24hrs so I need to take some rest and will try again later. Thanks